# Reverse engineering a schema from existing database with Slick

Tags: scala, database-schema, slick

I understand that the functionality to reverse engineer a schema from an existing database is in development for slick-2.
Could someone point me to the api for doing this and what the status of this functionality is.
Is it in master or do I need to switch branches? Pointers to any kind of doc for this feature would also be great.

Comment: PLEASE cross link concurrent Stack Overflow posts with Mailing list posts in the future. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/YeJ9DGbyTA8/IFX9phL9aGAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that will make it into 2.0 is in this PR
https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/233

There is no documentation at the moment besides the code. To understand how to use it you will have to look at

- [the type provider config files](https://github.com/slick/slick/tree/d497a1938fa0ba85fcf1b5a240ac931c2f91fbc6/test-dbs/type-provider/conf)
- [the Scala object `GeneratedClasses` that uses them to run the code-generator](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/d497a1938fa0ba85fcf1b5a240ac931c2f91fbc6/slick-testkit/src/test-config/scala/GeneratedClasses.scala)
- [the part of the sbt build file, that triggers `GeneratedClasses` during the build](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/d497a1938fa0ba85fcf1b5a240ac931c2f91fbc6/project/Build.scala)
- [the corresponding test cases](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/d497a1938fa0ba85fcf1b5a240ac931c2f91fbc6/slick-testkit/src/test/scala/scala/slick/test/jdbc/CodeGeneratorTest.scala)

(UPDATE: added links to the source code above)

There is also an older prototype which I wrote taking a different approach for Slick 1.0. bhudgeons wrote a blog post about how he used it https://bhudgeons.telegr.am/blog_posts/slick-tool-for-db-schema-generation

There has been some experimental work going on using type macros, but they wont make it into Scala, so we have to rewrite it for annotation macros at some point.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know when 2.0 is likely to be released? The usage for automatically getting the table definition from a database is not clear to me from the tests. Can you point me to the test case or some other simple example that does this.

Comment: 2.0 in 2013-Q4. I added links to the relevant parts of the source code. Example coming up until 2.0.